# Flutter shows blank screen for GridView/Listview in production build

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

I created a simple flutter app which basically shows grid items. In debug mode, the grid items shows normally. However, in production mode, flutter just shows blank screen. I even implemented pull to refresh. Now, when I pull to refresh the page, it still doesn't show.

In debug mode, both emulator and real device works fine. I use the following code to build the app for Android:

`flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi`

Here's my code: https://github.com/SanjayBanjade/flutter-ecommerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

https://github.com/SanjayBanjade/flutter-ecommerce/blob/master/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml